# Angular nested route not loading properly

Tags: javascript, angularjs, url-routing, angular-route-segment

**Issue #1**

I'm trying to customize the angular-route-provider example for myself.
I'm trying to implement individually separated tabs for each element in Section 1.

My section #/section1/hs(hs.html) still implements the #/section1/hs/X instead of #/section1/hs/ov for the tab.

You can see the app.js code [here](http://www.jamshedqureshi.com/angular/rs/app.js).

I've tried using prefs example & other methods but it doesn't work.

**Issue #2**

Also when I use another angular app path in templateUrl, the page doesn't seems to load properly(only texts are displayed).
Is it because one can't call another Angular app in the templateUrl. I'm not sure of this as I'm not an expert in AngularJS.

Below is my code for [this](http://www.jamshedqureshi.com/angular/rs/index.html) example.Any help would be appreciated.

**section1.html**:

```
<li ng-repeat="i in items" 
ng-class="{active:('s1.itemInfo' |  routeSegmentStartsWith) && 
('id' | routeSegmentParams) == i}">

<a ng-href="#{{'s1.itemInfo' | routeSegmentUrl: {id: i} }}">{{i}}</a>

</li>

<li ng-class="{active:('s1.hs' | routeSegmentStartsWith)}">
<a ng-href="#{{'s1.hs' | routeSegmentUrl }}">HTML/CSS</a>
</li>

<li ng-class="{active:('s1.prefs' | routeSegmentStartsWith)}">
<a ng-href="#{{'s1.prefs' | routeSegmentUrl }}">Preferences</a>
</li>
```

**hs.html**:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
<li ng-class="{active: $routeSegment.contains('ov')}">
<a href="#/section1/hs/ov">Overview</a>
</li>   
</ul>

<div app-view-segment="2" class="anim" No tab selected.> </div>
```

Comment: Why don't you use ui-router instead, it will more better in your case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you physically type in `/section1/hs/ov` will it navigate you to the correct page? Your misunderstanding is that by navigating to `s1.hs` that the tabs should be coming from `templates/secion1/hs.html` but it is overwritten by `.when('/section1/:id', 's1.itemInfo')`.

So, until you navigate to a directory higher that exists, in this case `section1/hs/ov`, the template will not be loaded. `/section1/anything/tab1` will result in still loading `tab1.html`, as the id is not really used for anything other than setting the header name.

To use a templateUrl to go to a different angular application, one that is not injected as a dependency in your app module declaration, you will need to do a page reload. If you set the templateUrl to `/templates/newapp.html` and in your html `ng-href={{'newapp' | routeSegmentUrl }}"`m making sure to omit the `#`, it should work.